# SASS @at-root, then LESS what to achieve the same function

Tags: sass, less

In `SASS`, in order to jump out of a nest, we can write like this:

```
div {
    color: #666;

    @at-root p {
        color: #f00;
    }
}
```

and then will be generated like this:

```
div {
    color: #666;
}

p {
    color: #f00;
}
```

but in `LESS`, how to achieve the same function?

Comment: What CSS is generated using SASS?

Comment: I think you can't do nothing similar in LESS

Comment: But I think it's a useful function, will be supported in the future?

Comment: There is a thread in github about a similar feature open since 2012, for the moment it doesn't seem to go to implement: https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1075

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in question comments there's no similar feature in LESS. There's a trick that uses LESS parent selector `&` and CSS pseudo-class `:not()`. It has some known bugs as useless parts in compiled CSS selectors.

```
div {
    color: #666;
    p:not(&){
        color: #f00;
    }
}
```

After compile:

```
div {
    color: #666;
}

p:not(div) {
    color: #f00;
}
```